# Relative Virtual Path Error in ASP Website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, mobile

I keep getting the error below when I try to load my website on a mobile device. I have searched the entire project for the virtual path it speaks of but cannot find where it is. Can anyone help me fix this error? It's got me scratching my head.

Server Error in '/' Application.

The relative virtual path 'Site.Mobile.Master' is not allowed here.

[image]

If I set the MasterPage directive to point to "Site.Mobile.Master" it gives me the following error message.

[image]

Comment: Check the @Page directive of your Default.aspx file and see whether you've set the MasterPageFile attribute to the "Site.Mobile.Master" file and see whether the path is correct

Comment: Here is the @Page directive. It looks good to me.
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

Comment: You must give the relative path. Not just the name of the master page. First find out where it's located in your project hierarchy

Comment: Bravo Sam. Thanks! Move your answer to an answer and Ill mark it as such!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion above the issue is in `@Page` directive's `MasterPageFile` attribute. You must  specify the virtual path with the Master page file name. First find out where it's located in your project hierarchy and then add the correct path in this attribute.

E.g.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Mobile.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

**TIP**

You won't get this issue if you select **Content Page** when you are adding a new page. At this time you'll be asked to select your master page and `MasterPageFile` attribute will be set correctly. If you add a **Web Form** you'll have to set this manually.

All the best!

Vote and accept answer if this helps :-)

Comment: This was exactly the fix.  Shame that nearly two years later, it's still this way, but thanks, Sam.

Comment: Glad it helped you mate! :)